# C++ Help with pointers for a student

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am trying to create a vector and pass it to a function allowing the vector to be modified. Here is an abridged version of my code that doesn't work.

```
void addStudent(vector<Student*>*);
int main()
{
   vector<Student*> students = new vector<Student*>;
   addStudent(students);
   return(0);
}
void addStudent(vector<Student*> *students)
{
   students->push_back(new Student("bob")); 
}
```

This code is compiling with errors. I think I'm not passing the pointer correctly but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've promised to give `addStudent` a pointer to a vector:

```
void addStudent(vector<Student*> *students)
```

so, use the address-of operator to get a pointer:

```
vector<Student*> students;
addStudent(&students);
```

There's nothing here that actually needs dynamic allocation, but if you did, note that `new` also returns a pointer:

```
vector<Student*>* students_ptr = new vector<Student*>();
addStudent(students_ptr);
```

Another option is to pass by reference:

```
void addStudent(vector<Student*>& students)
vector<Student*> students;
addStudent(students);
```

But I prefer the pointer, when the function is going to change its parameter.

Comment: @ZeroDivide: Nope, a downvote is different from undoing an upvote.  Right now I have upvotes from 4 users and a downvote from 1, plus your acceptance.

Comment: Weird... must have been someone else. Just a note: I wrote the program using the pass by reference method and the passing a pointer method. What is the advantage of pointer over reference. I come from a Java/C# background if that helps..

Comment: @ZeroDivide: A pointer can be pointed somewhere else.  If you have a pointer into an array, you can also do pointer math to find other elements of the array.  And a pointer makes the code look different, which is a clue to someone reading it that maybe this object lives longer than the function that created it, or maybe this function modifies its argument.  Both of those are possible with references but with references there's no clear sign that something is going on other than pass-by-value/return-by-value.

Comment: @ZeroDivide: And of course, null is a valid value for a pointer (although you can't then dereference it), and a null reference is invalid.  Practically speaking, though, they cause the same amount of trouble and indistunguishable runtime error messages.

Comment: @Ben: So since I need the vector<students> to persist until it is serialized to the disk, it is generally better to use a pointer rather than a reference?

Comment: @ZeroDivide: Since you're creating it in main, even an automatic variable will last for the whole life of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
vector<Student*> students = new vector<Student*>;
```

`students` is declared as a value type but you're assigning it a pointer.

In the future you should include the compiler error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably come from a `Java` background... so you'll have to learn to live without `new` for a while :)

In C++ there are 2 ways to create objects:

- objects with automatic storage duration (created on the stack)
- objects with dynamic storage duration (created on the heap)

`new` creates objects of the second kind, for which YOU must ensure proper disposal (by calling `delete` according to text books, but... we'll stay away from this for now).

Here, you don't need `new`:

```
std::vector<Student> students; // create an empty `vector` of `Student` objects

students.push_back(Student("bob")); // push a new Student in the vector
```

As for the function, you have several possibilities:

- make it return the object
- pass the object by reference `void addStudent(std::vector<Student>& students);`
- pass by pointer, but then use the *address of* operator to get to it `addStudent(&students);`

You don't have to use pointers everywhere in C++... in fact, it's probably better you don't, to begin with.

Oh, and you definitely need a good tutorial, that's basic stuff, and you can't get into C++ without the boring basics... sorry :/

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I do in fact come from Java/C# background and I'm doing the basics now for my languages class. My initial problem was the elements of the vector were not persisting after the function changed/added/deleted elements. I figured it had something to do with it not being a pointer. You've cleared up the difference between automatic storage and dynamic storage for me.

Comment: @ZeroDivide: I do recommend you to try and find a tutorial, in Java or C# you don't have to worry much about memory or lifetime of objects, it just works (most of the times), but C++ is different, so it takes some time and study to understand it... once you do however, you'll see the "automatic" language differently, and understanding it will help you become better :)